Не работает копирование последнего сообщения из телеграмм-чата через библиотеку Pyrogram
В общем была задача сделать код юзербота, который будет присылать определённое сообщение другому боту, а затем через 20 секунд читать последнее отправленное обратно(уже от бота юзеру сообщение), и добавлять его текст в переменную result. Получился такой код:
from pyrogram import Client
import time

api_id = ID
api_hash = "hash"

app = Client('my_account')

my_message = "Hello, this is a test message!"
result = ""

def send_message():
    app.send_message("@example_bot", my_message)

def copy_message():
    global result
    messages = app.get_history("@example_bot")
    for message in messages:
        if message.sender_id == "@example_bot":
            result = message.text
            break

send_message()
time.sleep(20)
copy_message()

print(result)

app.run()

И выдаётся такая ошибка:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Projects\Python\opa\Enigram\main.py", line 23, in 
send_message()   File "C:\Projects\Python\opa\Enigram\main.py", line 13, in send_message
app.send_message("@GptwitchBot", my_message)   File "C:\Projects\Python\opa\Enigram.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\sync.py",
line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
line 685, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Projects\Python\opa\Enigram.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\messages\send_message.py",
line 128, in send_message
peer=await self.resolve_peer(chat_id),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Projects\Python\opa\Enigram.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\advanced\resolve_peer.py",
line 59, in resolve_peer
raise ConnectionError("Client has not been started yet") ConnectionError: Client has not been started yet
Process finished with exit code 1

Всё перепробовал, но не понял, как исправить.
